# Cos'è "il lastrico" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Come tutti gli anni, i due fratelli viaggiavano avanti e indietro da giorni nel loro Millecento, il portabagagli carico dell’esplosivo che la notte di Capodanno avrebbe ucciso uccelli, spaventato cani gatti topi, fatto tremare le palazzine dagli scantinati fino al **lastrico**.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "lastrico" in questo brano. Nel vocabolario Treccani ho visto che questo termine si usa per indicare un pavimento fatto di lastre. Tuttavia, in questo contesto sembra indicare qualche parte di una palazzina.

Ho visto che questo vocabolo appare di nuovo più avanti nel libro:

> Facemmo un brindisi alle cose meravigliose che sarebbero accadute nell’anno nuovo, quindi cominciammo a sciamare verso il **lastrico**, i vecchi e i bambini con cappotti, sciarpe, perché faceva molto freddo. Mi accorsi che l’unico che si attardava svogliatamente di sotto era Alfonso. Lo chiamai per buona educazione, non mi sentì o fece finta di non sentirmi. Corsi di sopra. Mi ritrovai sulla testa un cielo tremendo, zeppo di stelle e di tenebra, gelato.

E appare anche in quest'altro passaggio:

> Ma appena chiusi la porta e fui sul pianerottolo Lila mi chiamò. Era all’ultimo piano, salii in punta di piedi. Se ne stava raggomitolata accanto alla porta del **lastrico**, nella penombra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il *lastrico solare* è la copertura superiore di uno stabile, se non c'è il tetto con le tegole. Può essere simile al pavimento di un terrazzo, con la differenza che sul terrazzo condominiale ci si può andare normalmente, per esempio a stendere i panni, mentre sul lastrico solare no, anche se ovviamente c'è la porta per raggiungerlo nel caso in cui, ad esempio, si debbano fare dei lavori di manutenzione.

In pratica il terrazzo che fa da tetto ad alcuni palazzi è un lastrico con la ringhiera o il parapetto.

Ecco un esempio pratico per chiarire la differenza tra i due:

[image]

Comment: Ho fatto il secondo brano un po' più lungo, così si capisce meglio che vanno alla parte alta della palazzina, quindi il significato di "lastrico" penso sia lo stesso degli altri passaggi. Vanno là per lanciare i fuochi d'artificio di Capodanno.

Comment: @Charo, ottimo, allora in tutti e tre i casi intende il lastrico solare, posto perfetto per lanciare i fuochi d'artificio :)! P.S. = con prudenza!

Comment: E non potrebbe essere anche il terrazzo posto alla parte superiore della palazzina?  Non capisco come possono essere tutti sul "lastrico solare" a lanciare i fuochi d'artificio.

Comment: Infatti, adesso mi accorgo che, un po' più avanti del secondo brano che ho riportato, l'autrice scrive questo: «Le esplosioni causate dai Solara stavano diventando sempre più potenti, un loro razzo invece di finire in cielo scoppiò contro il parapetto del nostro terrazzo con un bagliore rosso fragoroso e fumo soffocante.»

Comment: @Charo sì, è praticamente la stessa cosa, solo che in genere il terrazzo è sistemato in modo da poter essere fruibile, mentre il lastrico solare può essere anche solo incatramato in superficie, per cui ci si va solo per lavori di manutenzione (o per lanciare i fuochi d'artificio)...

Comment: Potresti modificare un po' la risposta per includere il contenuto dei commenti?

Comment: @Charo ho aggiunto una foto del lastrico del condominio di mia mamma, è un bell'esempio della differenza tra terrazzo e lastrico puro e semplice, ciao!